# Saving 700 images locally from an XML file which loads every 5 minutes

Tags: php

I have an application that reads an xml file every 5 minutes (using a cronjob) and saves about 700 url's to images inside a database.
After 5 minutes, most of the images are deleted and the process begins again.

My site would be allot faster if i'd save the images locally but I want some advice on the way to do it.

1. I tried using fopen, curl - but writing so many images at once just brakes everything down.
2. How about saving them as bloob? How much will this affect the speed?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not suggest storing as blob, instead you can save the locally stored image name into database. Storing so many images in blob will require a great resource unnecessarily.

You can try this out.
When you access that xml file get all the url and store in to temp table say `unsaved_images_url` with a `id` and `url` as column.

Then locally fetch the rows from above tables and save images on disk. This can be done shell script or something I am not sure. And after you have saved the image locally delete that row from database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to rename them then why not just do something along these lines (assuming $images is an array of URLs):

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    exec("wget $image");
}
```

It would be faster than creating and writing to a file.